# Automate dekstop screening with Python

Tags: python-2.7, pdfminer

I am trying to make a program that could automatically scan the images or texts on a user's desktop and then convert it to a `.txt` file for text analysis.

So far I have found source codes to convert `PDF` and `HTML` into `.txt`. However I would like to make my program automatically scan the desktop screen at certain time intervals rather than manually inputting the source such as:

```
$pdf2txt.py samples/simple1.pdf
```

I don't know where to start so any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the desktop is just a location in the file directory like:

```
C:\Users\Kirsteen\Desktop
```

So the next step would be to search through this directory for the types of files you are interested in. You'd be aiming to generate a list of valid file names that need to be converted. This [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python) might help you.

Once the files have been found run those converting scripts you have. To repeat this automatically put all of this in a loop and add a delay so that it runs once an hour/week.

To tidy things up, think about running this process in the background and making sure the program doesn't convert the files more than once if they haven't changed.